# Find nearest position to target position by a specific distance

Tags: c#

I have two positions and want to calculate the position where the red star is. (I want to move B to the "red star location" but I don't know the coordinates.)

[image: desc]

I have the position of A and B and a minimum distance from position A. So my question is how do I calculate the nearest position to B within the specified distance.

Hope someone understand what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What if B was inside the outer circle?

Comment: is the radius around A known?

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D space?

Comment: If B is inside the outer circle then B is in range and does not have to move.

Comment: The radius is not known, all I have is a distance away from A that I wanna reach.

Comment: This is 2D only X and Y.

Comment: SO is not appropriate for this type of question. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ maybe.

Comment: So you're trying to move your object B towards the position of the "red star" which is always on the line between the center of A and B?

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @gnat I wasn't encouraging him to cross-post, but rather move the question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- You want B to be in the same direction from A as before
- You want to move B to a specific distance from A

  - If B is farther away, move it closer to A to get to the distance
  - If B is closer than the specific distance, move it away from A to get to the distance

Then this is the way to do it:

1. Calculate the current distance from A to B
2. Calculate the difference in position between A and B (in 2 or 3 dimensions)
3. Divide this difference by a ratio that is "current distance / wanted distance"
   For instance, if the current distance is 2x as far away from A as you want, you would divide the difference in position by 2
4. Set the new position of B to be A + the new differences

Here's some sample code:

```
var wantedDistance = 40.0;
var distance = Math.Sqrt((A.x - B.x)*(A.x - B.x) + (A.y - B.y)*(A.y - B.y));
var diffX = B.x - A.x;
var diffY = B.y - A.y;

var ratio = distance / wantedDistance;
var newDiffX = diffX / ratio;
var newDiffY = diffY / ratio;

var newB = new PointF(A.x + newDiffX, A.y + newDiffY);
```

In a comment you say that if B is inside the radius, then it is in range so it should not be moved. You would simply handle this by comparing `distance` with `wantedDistance` and if lower, then you're done. Simply add this line of code after the `var distance = ...` line:

```
if (distance < wantedDistance)
    return B; // or whatever you want to do when "done"
```

If you need to do this in 3D space, simply augment every calculation and diff to handle the Z dimension as well.